# Uniquenesses component of explorator yfactor analysis

Tags: r, pca, dimensionality-reduction, exploratory-data-analysis

I am applying an Exploratory factor analysis on a dataset using the factanal() package in R. After applying Scree Test I found out that 2 factors need to be retained from 20 features.

Trying to find what this uniqueness represents, I found the following from [here](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-factor-analysis/)

"A high uniqueness for a variable usually means it doesn’t fit neatly into our factors. ..... If we subtract the uniquenesses from 1, we get a quantity called the communality. The communality is the proportion of variance of the ith variable contributed by the m common factors. ......In general, we’d like to see low uniquenesses or high communalities, depending on what your statistical program returns."

I understand that if the value of uniquenesses is high, it could be better represented in a single factor. But what is a good threshold for this uniquenesses measure? All of my features show a value greater than 0.3, and most of them range from 0.3 to 0.7. Does the following mean that my factor analysis doesn't work well on my data? I have tried rotation, the results are not very different. What else should I try then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition an indicator variable's variance into its...

1. Uniqueness (h2): Variance that is not explained by the common factors
2. Communality (1-h2): The variance that is explained by the common factors

Which values can be considered "good" depends on your context. You should look for examples in your application domain to know what you can expect. In the package psych, you can find some examples from psychology:

```
library(psych)
m0 <- fa(Thurstone.33,2,rotate="none",fm="mle")
m0
m0$loadings
```

When you run the code, you can see that the communalities are around 0.6. The absolute factor loadings of the unrotated solution vary between 0.27 and 0.85.

An absolute value of 0.4 is often used as an arbitrary cutoff for acceptable factor loadings in psychological domains.